# Worklight 6.0 Android Hybrid Application not going to the login page

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

We have developed a hybrid application for Android using worklight 6.0.

The application invokes a query for which form-based authentication is required.
Device authentication and worklight authentication as well are used in application.

When invoking the query, the app will call the worklight server using web service and pass the login page html as the response - *This is not working in Android device* since the response is not reaching the app and the app gets hung after a timeout without being able to redirect to the login page.

We are using Server level authentication where the WebSphere is integrated with LDAP.
The User authentication happens successfully with LDAP and the session gets authenticated. The resources are secured with predefined Worklight security tests for XSRF, Remote Disable etc.

Also the resources are secured with Device Auto Provisioning and Application Authentication. Once the user gets authenticated with LDAP, the device authentication fails and the application hangs

The same application is working fine in iOS.

**Logs**

```
 07-10 19:45:13.241: I/chromium(25549): [INFO:CONSOLE(978)] "processMessage failed: Stack: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    07-10 19:45:13.241: I/chromium(25549):     at invokeProcedure (file:///data/data/com.MOIKuwait/files/www/default/wlclient/js/wlclient.js:1686:23)
    07-10 19:45:13.241: I/chromium(25549):     at file:///data/data/com.MOIKuwait/files/www/default/js/common.js:2737:40
    07-10 19:45:13.241: I/chromium(25549):     at captureReturnValue (file:///data/data/com.MOIKuwait/files/www/default/wlclient/js/cordova.js:852:20)
    07-10 19:45:13.241: I/chromium(25549):     at Object.cordova.callbackFromNative (file:///data/data/com.MOIKuwait/files/www/default/wlclient/js/cordova.js:293:54)
    07-10 19:45:13.241: I/chromium(25549):     at processMessage (file:///data/data/com.MOIKuwait/files/www/default/wlclient/js/cordova.js:971:21)
    07-10 19:45:13.241: I/chromium(25549):     at Function.androidExec.processMessages (file:///data/data/com.MOIKuwait/files/www/default/wlclient/js/cordova.js:1009:17)
    07-10 19:45:13.241: I/chromium(25549):     at Object.androidExec [as exec] (file:///data/data/com.MOIKuwait/files/www/default/wlclient/js/cordova.js:861:21)
    07-10 19:45:13.241: I/chromium(25549):     at WL.Device.getNetworkInfo (file:///data/data/com.MOIKuwait/files/www/default/wlclient/js/wlgap.android.js:1251:13)
    07-10 19:45:13.241: I/chromium(25549):     at inquireVisaApplicationStatus (file:///data/data/com.MOIKuwait/files/www/default/js/common.js:2726:15)
    07-10 19:45:13.241: I/chromium(25549):     at validateAppNumber (file:///data/data/com.MOIKuwait/files/www/default/js/common.js:680:3)", source: file:///data/data/com.MOIKuwait/files/www/default/wlclient/js/cordova.js (978)
```

**authenticationConfig.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<tns:loginConfiguration xmlns:tns="http://www.worklight.com/auth/config"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <securityTests>

        <mobileSecurityTest name="WASTest-securityTest">
                    <testAppAuthenticity />
            <testDeviceId provisioningType="none" />
            <testUser realm="WASLTPARealm" />
        </mobileSecurityTest>

        <mobileSecurityTest name="PushNotificationSecurityTest">
            <testAppAuthenticity />
            <testDeviceId provisioningType="none" />
            <testUser realm="PushRealm" />
        </mobileSecurityTest>

    </securityTests>

    <realms>

        <realm loginModule="WASLTPAModule" name="WASLTPARealm">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.WebSphereFormBasedAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="login-page" value="/login.html" />
            <parameter name="error-page" value="/loginError.html" />
        </realm>

        <realm name="PushRealm" loginModule="HeaderLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator</className>
        </realm>

    </realms>

    <loginModules>

        <loginModule name="WASLTPAModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.WebSphereLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule>

        <loginModule name="HeaderLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderLoginModule</className>
            <parameter name="user-name-header" value="userid" />
        </loginModule>

    </loginModules>

</tns:loginConfiguration>
```

**invoking the adapter**

```
if(networkInfo.isNetworkConnected == "true"){
var invocationData = {
adapter : 'EnquiryServicesAdapter',
procedure : 'inquirePassportData',
parameters : [ UserUID ]
};
WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
onSuccess : successPassportResponse,
onFailure : failPassportResponse,
timeout : requestTimeout
});
```

**EnquriyServiceAdapter.js**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Licensed Materials - Property of IBM 5725-G92 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 
    2011, 2013. All Rights Reserved. US Government Users Restricted Rights - 
    Use, duplication or disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with 
    IBM Corp. -->
<wl:adapter name="EnquiryServicesAdapter" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:wl="http://www.worklight.com/integration" xmlns:http="http://www.worklight.com/integration/http">

    <displayName>EnquiryServicesAdapter</displayName>
    <description>EnquiryServicesAdapter</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <domain>localhost</domain>
            <port>9080</port>
            <!-- Following properties used by adapter's key manager for choosing specific 
                certificate from key store <sslCertificateAlias></sslCertificateAlias> <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword> -->
        </connectionPolicy>
        <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />
    </connectivity>

    <procedure name="inquirePassportData" securityTest="WASTest-securityTest" />


</wl:adapter>
```

**EnquiryServicesAdapter-impl**

```
function inquirePassportData(userId) {

    var instance = com.worklight.service.PassportEnquiryService.getInstance();

    var sessionInstance = WL.Server.getActiveUser('WASLTPARealm');

    WL.Logger.info(sessionInstance.userId);

    return {
        response : instance.getEnquiryDetails(sessionInstance.userId)
    };
}
```

Comment: does it work if you remove the security test for the procedure inquirePassportData ?

Comment: Also, just to check, do you have the functions successPassportResponse and failPassportResponse actually implemented ?

Answer (score 0):

According to your logs wlclient is expecting to get a function, but receiving an undefined instead. the call is coming from common.js, line 2737. This file is your application code. I'd put a breakpoint there and check whats going on. Hard to say without seeing that part of code.

You can read more about debugging your JS code running on Android here - https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging